# R: How to match a pattern that does not begin with another pattern?

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, grepl

I have a column with a series of products for each customer that I want to identify in another column with a 0 or 1. Here is an example:

```
products <- c("APV", "SAPV, APV", "SCA, FFMM, APV", "SCA, SAPV", "FFMM, APV", "FFMM", "SCA, SAPV, APV", "SCA, SAPV, FFMM, FFAC", "SCA, FFMM", "SAPV", "SCA", "SCA, APV", "SAPV, FFMM", "SCA, SAPV, FFMM, APV", "SAPV, FFMM, APV")
```

I want to create a column names APV that identifies if there is an APV in the list, but only "APV", if i just use

```
grepl("APV", products)
```

it will identify also SAPV.

I know it is a relatively easy question but I couldn't make it work

Comment: `grepl("APV", products, ignore.case = TRUE, fixed = TRUE, useBytes = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a word boundary like this

```
products <- c("APV", "SAPV, APV", "SCA, FFMM, APV", "SCA, SAPV", "FFMM, APV", "FFMM", "SCA, SAPV, APV", "SCA, SAPV, FFMM, FFAC", "SCA, FFMM", "SAPV", "SCA", "SCA, APV", "SAPV, FFMM", "SCA, SAPV, FFMM, APV", "SAPV, FFMM, APV")
grepl("\\bAPV\\b", products)
```

Which yields

```
 [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

See a demo for the [**expression on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/KhQJNW/1).